# The application of undamped simple harmonic vibrations in the world

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the application of the following problem in the world? Can you give an important application? And what is the hystorical aspect of it? Why did this problem arise?

[image]

This problem is in the simmons differential equation book.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean what could be the applications of the equation in question, namely $$x''+ax=0,$$
not of the example or of the problem (actually the car is going to hit the wall, so the movement is really not given by this equation... but that's only an example).

The truth is that the equation is so simple that it can hardly have important applications or applications at all (for a similar reason, it is unlikely that anyone can point out much history about it, although one could provide various other problems that lead to the same equation). Moreover, since the solutions are quite explicit we could argue that we really don't need the equation, but only the solutions and/or their oscillatory properties.

I regret thus having to note that nowadays, it is only one among various others equations that appear in introductory books really because we should start with the simplest possible examples.